# Fill Path in Metal

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I creating a drawing Application in Metal. I need to create a Fill path using the users touchpoints. What algorithm can we used to achieve that effect in Metal. Here's an example image showing what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: You already asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647517/filling-in-metal).

Comment: It is not flood Fill. It is related to Clip Ear or Delaunay Traingulation ...

Comment: Here when user moves the finger. It need to fill the path like mentioned in this image https://imgur.com/gallery/QltsmdK

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234705/fast-rasterizing-of-text-and-vector-art might prove useful for you.

Comment: Robustly filling polybeziers on a GPU is a seriously non-trivial task. This question is frankly too broad to answer. If you had an idea of which algorithm you wanted to try to implement (whether based on RAVG, Loop-Blinn, stencil-then-cover, etc.) then you could ask more meaningful questions about how to do it in Metal. At this level, it's not about your choice of API or shading language; it's about analyzing the problem space and the literature deeply enough to find an approach that fits.

Comment: @warrenm currently i am doing bezier algorithm to find the points in the curve. For example first I found around 30 points for the using Bezier algorithm ABCD and then   30 points in between BCDE. I need to fill the points like this triangulation. https://imgur.com/gallery/4v7LBpZ

Comment: If you're already successfully flatting the path into a (potentially self-intersecting) sequence of linear segments, it sounds like you could use [libtess2](https://github.com/memononen/Libtess2) to produce a mesh, which you could then rasterize with Metal. Rasterizing directly from a Bezier path is significantly harder.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903777/triangulation-in-metal) I added and editted some improvements in the question