# Triangulation in Metal

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

[image]

As Shown in the picture. The numbers are touchpoints in the screen in order. I need to draw the traingulation only inside Colored area. Can we do it in metal with its algorithm or Any suggestions please

```
var temp1:VertexInFillBrus
temp1 = VertexInFillBrush(a:drawPoints[0] , b:drawPoints[drawPoints.count - 1] , c: drawPoints[drawPoints.count - 2]))
self.bezierCalculatedCoordinates.append(temp1)
self.buildBuffers(device: device)
```

In Draw Command

```
commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState!)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(texture, index: 0)
commandEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: .triangle, indexCount: 3 , indexType: .uint16, indexBuffer: indexBuffer!, indexBufferOffset: 0 ,instanceCount:bezierCalculatedCoordinates.count)
```

In shader

```
struct VertexOutFillBrush {
    float4 pos[[position]];
    float2 currentTextureCoordinates;
};
struct VertexInFillBrush
{
    float2 a;
    float2 b;
    float2 c;
};
```

Vertex Shader

```
 vertex VertexOutFillBrush fillBrushVertex(constant VertexInFillBrush *allParams[[buffer(0)]],
                                            uint vertexId [[vertex_id]],
                                            uint instanceId [[instance_id]])
    {

        VertexInFillBrush params = allParams[instanceId];
        VertexOutFillBrush vo;
        half2 pos;
        ushort x = (vertexId % 3) ;
        switch (x) {

            case 0:
                pos.x = params.a.x ;//+   0.06 * sinpi(params.angle)  * 3.0/4.0  ;
                pos.y = params.a.y ;//-    0.06 * cospi(params.angle);
                vo.currentTextureCoordinates =  float2(1 * pos.x/2.0 + 0.5 , -1 * pos.y/2.0 + 0.5);
                break;
            case 1:
                pos.x = params.b.x ;//+   0.06 * sinpi(params.angle)  * 3.0/4.0  ;
                pos.y = params.b.y ;//-
                 vo.currentTextureCoordinates =  float2(1 * pos.x/2.0 + 0.5 , -1 * pos.y/2.0 + 0.5);
                break;

         default:
                pos.x = params.c.x ;
                pos.y = params.c.y  ;
                vo.currentTextureCoordinates =  float2(1 * pos.x/2.0 + 0.5 , -1 * pos.y/2.0 + 0.5);
                break;
        }
        vo.pos.xy = float2(pos);
        vo.pos.zw = float2(0, 1);

        return vo;
    }
```

In fragment Shader

```
fragment float4 fillBrushFragment(VertexOutFillBrush params[[stage_in]],
                                    texture2d<float , access::sample>texture [[texture(0)]])
{

    constexpr sampler defaultSampler;
    float4 color = float4(texture.sample(defaultSampler, float2(params.currentTextureCoordinates))) ;
    if(color.w > 0.02){
        return float4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    }
    return float4(1.0,1.0,0.0,0.5);

}
```

Comment: Metal is a low-level API and as such doesn't have facilities for triangulating complex polygons. As I mentioned on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859460/fill-path-in-metal), which is very close to an exact duplicate of this one, you'll need to use a tessellation algorithm like the one provided by [libtess2](https://github.com/memononen/Libtess2).

Comment: @warrenm for other question https://imgur.com/gallery/SU6Yggj I found a algorithm by which drawing a triangle between starting point to last two points like [0,1,2],[0,2,3],[0,3,4],[0,4,5].....

Comment: For this as well similar algorithm will work. https://imgur.com/gallery/4IE3rcH as mentioned in the picture. I could execute the algorithm as in above comment. Now I want to remove the overlapped area. For that I am passing doing rendering in Off Screen. I am passing that texture to shader. I added my Shader code to the question. But I could not get the expected results.

Comment: In Fragment Shader I am checking whether there is already a alpha value if it is there I am just making it zero to remove the color.(Overlapped areas will become alpha zero)

Comment: @warrenm Can I do like this. What is wrong in this. The blending is disabled..

Comment: output https://imgur.com/gallery/S70FkOb https://imgur.com/gallery/wLZiR6U outputs